# How to use map function to return multiple keys from an array of objects? ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

If I have an array of objects

```
var bitcoinData = [
{
  "date": "2013-05-01",
  "txVolume(USD)": 108659660.293,
  "txCount": 52443,
  "marketcap(USD)": 1542820000,
  "price(USD)": 139,
  "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
  "generatedCoins": 3575,
  "fees": 36.80599998,
  "activeAddresses": null
},
{
  "date": "2013-05-02",
  "txVolume(USD)": 96958519.0041,
  "txCount": 55169,
  "marketcap(USD)": 1292190000,
  "price(USD)": 116.38,
  "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
  "generatedCoins": 3425,
  "fees": 54.40791613,
  "activeAddresses": null
```

How can I create an array containing only the date and price of each day by using the map function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The naming "price(USD)" causes a problem for destructuring. 
So used basic instead. Here you go.

```js
const bitcoinData = [
{
  "date": "2013-05-01",
  "txVolume(USD)": 108659660.293,
  "txCount": 52443,
  "marketcap(USD)": 1542820000,
  "price(USD)": 139,
  "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
  "generatedCoins": 3575,
  "fees": 36.80599998,
  "activeAddresses": null
},
{
  "date": "2013-05-02",
  "txVolume(USD)": 96958519.0041,
  "txCount": 55169,
  "marketcap(USD)": 1292190000,
  "price(USD)": 116.38,
  "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
  "generatedCoins": 3425,
  "fees": 54.40791613,
  "activeAddresses": null
  }];
  
  const summary = bitcoinData.map(item => ({ date: item.date, price: item["price(USD)"] }));
  
  console.log(summary);
```

Solved the destructuring issue, here it is using that technique.

```js
    const bitcoinData = [
    {
      "date": "2013-05-01",
      "txVolume(USD)": 108659660.293,
      "txCount": 52443,
      "marketcap(USD)": 1542820000,
      "price(USD)": 139,
      "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
      "generatedCoins": 3575,
      "fees": 36.80599998,
      "activeAddresses": null
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-05-02",
      "txVolume(USD)": 96958519.0041,
      "txCount": 55169,
      "marketcap(USD)": 1292190000,
      "price(USD)": 116.38,
      "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
      "generatedCoins": 3425,
      "fees": 54.40791613,
      "activeAddresses": null
      }];
      
      const summary = bitcoinData.map(({ date, "price(USD)": price }) => ({ date, price }));
      
      console.log(summary);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Done**

```js
var bitcoinData = [
{
  "date": "2013-05-01",
  "txVolume(USD)": 108659660.293,
  "txCount": 52443,
  "marketcap(USD)": 1542820000,
  "price(USD)": 139,
  "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
  "generatedCoins": 3575,
  "fees": 36.80599998,
  "activeAddresses": null
},
{
  "date": "2013-05-02",
  "txVolume(USD)": 96958519.0041,
  "txCount": 55169,
  "marketcap(USD)": 1292190000,
  "price(USD)": 116.38,
  "exchangeVolume(USD)": 0,
  "generatedCoins": 3425,
  "fees": 54.40791613,
  "activeAddresses": null
 }]
 
 console.log(bitcoinData.map(data=> {
 return {
   date: data.date,
   'price(USD)': data['price(USD)']
 }})
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bitcoinData.map(element => {
    return ({"date":element.date, "price(USD)":element["price(USD)"]})
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
BitCoinData.map(bitCoin => {date: bitcoin.date, price: bitcoin.price});
```

This should return an array of objects containing only the date and price

Comment: This code won't even run. You should wrap the curly braces with some parenthesis.